# a finite $p$-group of class two such that $Z(G)$ is not subgroup of $\Phi(G)$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group of class two such that $Z(G)$ is not subgroup of $\Phi(G)$. Also let $T$ be the minimal set of generators of $G$. Then
do there exists  a finite $p$-group $G$  of class two such that  $|x|<\exp(Z(G))$ for any $x\in T\cap Z(G)$?

Thank you

Comment: What is $exp(Z(G))$?

Comment: @Nishant: it is the exponent of $Z(G)$.

Comment: Let $H$ be a group with $H'=Z(H)$ having exponent $p^2$, and $G = H \times C_p$. Then elements of $T \cap Z(G)$ lie in the direct factor $C_p$ so they have order $p$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: very nice as always. Thank you

Comment: Wait, why can't a central element in the $H$ factor be in a minimal generating set?

Comment: @Nishant The elements of $\Phi(H)$ are "non-generators" - elements that can be excluded from any generating set - and $Z(H) = H^{\prime}\leq\Phi(H) = \Phi(G)$, since $\Phi(C_{p})=1$.